# Find inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I need to find an inner product in $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $\{(1,i),(-1,i)\}$ is orthonormal.

##### I tried the following:

I know that $\langle(1,i),(1,i)\rangle=\langle(-1,i),(-1,i)\rangle=1$ and $\langle(1,i),(-1,i)\rangle=0$.

So I say that $v=(x,y)=\alpha(1,i)+\beta(-1,i)$ and $w=(x',y')=\alpha'(1,i)+\beta'(-1,i)$.

Solving $(x,y)=(\alpha-\beta,\alpha i+\beta i)$, I get that $\alpha=\frac{x-yi}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{-x-yi}{2}$, and in the same way we get the value of $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$.

So I get that the inner product is $\langle(v,w)\rangle=\langle(x,y),(x',y')\rangle=\overline{'}+\overline{'}=\left(\frac{x-yi}{2}\right)\left(\frac{x'+y'i}{2}\right) +\left(\frac{-x-yi}{2}\right)\left(\frac{-x'+y'i}{2}\right)$

But when I try it, it gives me that $\langle(1,i),(-1,i)\rangle=1$

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: you have brackets that don't match.

Comment: Where do you mean that the brackets do not match?

Comment: I fixed the deadly bracket mismatch, averting sure disaster. Bracket Man to the rescue.

Comment: Time to introduce the 'Bracket Fixer' badge, methinks.

Comment: Let $u,v$ be the two vectors. Check that $\|u\|^2 = \|v\|^2 = 2$ and $u^*v = 0$, so the map $(u,v) \mapsto {1 \over 2} u^*v$ will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables $x, y, x'$ and $y'$ are potentially complex (perhaps use $z$'s and $w$'s next time!), and this needs to be taken into account when you take conjugates in the final step. We have
$$\overline{\alpha'} = \overline{\frac{x'-iy'}{2}} = \frac{\overline{x'} + i \overline{y'}}{2}$$
and
$$\overline{\beta'} = \overline{\frac{-x'-iy'}{2}} = \frac{-\overline{x'} + i \overline{y'}}{2},$$
which gives us
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
\alpha \overline{\alpha'} + \beta \overline{\beta'} &= \bigg(\frac{x-iy}{2} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{\overline{x'} + i \overline{y'}}{2} \bigg) + \bigg(\frac{-x-iy}{2} \bigg) \bigg(\frac{-\overline{x'} + i \overline{y'}}{2} \bigg)\\ 
& = \frac{1}{4}\big(2x\overline{x'} + 2y\overline{y'}\big)
\end{split} 
\end{equation}